# Remove view when touchesEnded is called

Tags: swift

I use touchesBegan to add a view on the screen when user touches and holds the finger on the screen

See example below

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.location(in: view)
            let dot = CustomTouch(frame: CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 80, height: 80))
            dot.backgroundColor = randomColors[0]
            self.view.addSubview(dot)
        }
    }
```

I want to detect when user lifts up the finger from the screen, then remove the view that was added at that position. I would like some ideas on how to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Add a property for the added view instead of creating on the fly and then remove if existent on touchesEnded:

```
var dot: CustomTouch?

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: view)
        dot = CustomTouch(frame: CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 80, height: 80))
        dot.backgroundColor = randomColors[0]
        self.view.addSubview(dot)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    dot?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: this won't work when user touches the screen with multiple fingers

Comment: This is just the theory, you have to adjust the touchesBegan and touchesEnded to detect only the touches you want and execute the code to remove the custom view you added.

Comment: check the event object for the allTouches count or change your approach and add a gesture recognizer to the view

Answer (score 0):

This did the work for me:
1) create a dictionary to store each created 'CustomTouch' for that specific touch
2) when touchesEnded, I will remove the object that key (UITouch)